# help writing sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a database that looks like:

**contacts**

```
id | name
1  | bob
2  | jack
3  | jill
```

**contactsGroupLink**

```
cId| gId
1  | 1
2  | 3
2  | 3
2  | 5
3  | 4
```

So basically,

a contact is linked to a group by an entry in the contactsGroupLink table.

A contact may be in multiple groups, but a contact may only be on a group once.

The query I want to write is

```
select `name` 
  from contacts 
 where contact.id not in (select contactId 
                           from contactsGroupLink 
                          where groupId = 5);
```

Which works.
It returns `bob` and `jill`.

however its not very optimized as it has a dependent sub-query. can anyone help optimize it?

Comment: Haha, I really do need to stop adding a "hi" message don't I...

Comment: What you have might be more optimized than a table join. I think you would have to performance test the two to be 100% sure though.

Comment: Im not even sure how I would write the join query....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both columns are unlikely to be NULL, in [MySQL (**only**) the best option is to use the LEFT JOIN/IS NULL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/):

```
   SELECT c.name
     FROM CONTACTS c
LEFT JOIN CONTACTSGROUPLINK cgl ON cgl.contactid = c.id
                               AND cgl.groupid = 5
    WHERE cgl.contactid IS NULL
```

[If the columns were nullable](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/), `NOT EXISTS` is a better choice:

```
   SELECT c.name
     FROM CONTACTS c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                        FROM CONTACTSGROUPLINK cgl
                       WHERE cgl.contactid = c.id
                         AND cgl.groupid = 5)
```

The two columns in the `CONTACTSGROUPLINK` table should be the primary key, which will automatically index the columns (as of ~5.0+?).  Otherwise, make sure the columns are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

...

```
where not exists (
  select 1 from contactsGroupLink cgl
  where cgl.contactid = contact.id and cgl.groupid = 5
)
```

This should efficiently use the index by contactsGroupLink(contactid, groupid) you already have.